# Difference between Model.find({key: "value"}) and Model.find().where("key").equals("value") in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Consider the following code

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch((err) => console.log(err));

const Model = mongoose.model('collection', new mongoose.Schema({ ... }));

async function main() {
  const connection = await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/DB`); 
  // Method 1 
  const doc1 = await Model.find({ key: 'value' });
  console.log(doc1); 
  // Method 2 
  const doc2 = await Model.find().where('key').equals('value');
  mongoose.connection.close();
  console.log(doc1);
}
```

`Model.find()` returns a `<Query>` Object which is *chainable*.

Q1• What is a `<Query>` Object. Is it a *promise*?

Q2• What is the difference between *Method1* and *Method2* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. The `<Query>` Object, is not a promise. You should note, `Model.find()` does not return a promise, it is not asynchronous and your wouldn't use `await`. `<Query>` is an instance of the Query class. It contains information about your query and has a number of functions available to it such as `where()` and `equals()`.

A full list of functions is available here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query

It is the returned `<Query>` Object which allows the chaining.

Q2. The main difference between these two methods is semantic. They both perform the same function. *Method 1* allows you to pass the query parameters as an object. *Method 2* performs the same action through function chaining.